# Post method from xamarin string and image MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

i am trying to upload a photo with data to server using asp.net web api. while  i am trying to test the api with postman and debug time with xamarin emulator also api is working fine and stored the photo and data to database. when i try the same thing in physical device, result will return success but no data or picture stored. what i am doing the wrong with my below code.

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

content.Add(new StreamContent(_PicFile.GetStream()),
    "\"file\"",
    $"\"{_PicFile.Path}\"");

try
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://sitelink:123/api/Visit/UploadFiles?" + "CustID="+CustID+"&TrID="+_TrID+"&CreatedBy="+Settings.UserName;
    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
    var res = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    ResultLabel.Text ="  File Uploaded Successfully ";
    ResultLabel.TextColor = Color.Green;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ResultLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

I got no error instead getting success but same time not working what i expected.

Comment: Check status code of response to make sure the server return HTTP Status 200 OK

Comment: sure it returns 200. sorry i didnt mention that i have getting expected result in debug time also with xamarin emulator. i will update the question. this issue is in physical mobile.

Comment: @Zahya which Emulator were you able to make it work from Android or iOS? Was the sdk/api level of the emulator the same as the physical device?

Comment: @Zahya Please check whether `_PicFile` on your real device has the valid data. If it is an empty image, the data on your server will be null.